# найти несколько ссылок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно найти ссылки, которые имеют атрибут href="tel:...". Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как это можно сделать вообще?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[href^='tel:']")
```

если кому нужно будет :)